# What is the design pattern to use when you need two borrows in Rust?

Tags: rust, design-patterns

Here is a Rust function.

```
impl Room {
  pub fn getPageContent(&mut self, bookNumber: u32, pageNumber: u16, alp: &Alphabet) {
    let page = &mut self.books[(bookNumber-1) as usize].pages[(pageNumber-1) as usize];
    if page.text.is_empty() {
      page.generateContent(alp, bookNumber, &self);
    }
  }
}
```

Each page needs information from to room in order to generate its content.
However, doing that as show in the function of course leads to

```
cannot borrow `self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable´
```

My question is : what is the intended design pattern to be used in such cases ? Especially at scale, as this is only an example.

Giving the page each information it needs from the Room would be a solution if all those informations implement Clone, but doesn't seem advisable (what if ´generateContent´ needs 10 different informations ? Such a pattern would quickly multiply to work to be done along with potential mistakes and overall complexity).

Another solution is to generate the content directly in the ´getPageContent´, but this pattern would quickly lead to having *everything* be done inside Room, which does not seem to be a good idea either when applied at scale either.

Comment: What do you mean "design pattern"?

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the mutation out of `generateContent` then change `generateContent` to take a non-mut reference.

```rust
pub fn get_page_content(&mut self, book_number: u32, page_number: u16, alp: &Alphabet) {
    let page = &self.books[(book_number - 1) as usize].pages[(page_number - 1) as usize];
    if page.text.is_empty() {
        let text = page.generate_content(alp, book_number, self);

        // lookup the page again but mut this time
        let page =
            &mut self.books[(book_number - 1) as usize].pages[(page_number - 1) as usize];
        page.text = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: It indeed works, but is not a very nice solution because I'm taking out of Page a process that really should be internal to it. The root problem is still the same, this is only a workaround that is only for the compiler's benefit, not the humans reading the code.